# How would I go about wrapping or line-breaking an entire sentence in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, paragraph

Let's say I have the following text containing two sentences.

```
<p>This is my first sentence. This is my second sentence that should be on the next line.</p>
```

Instead of having only the end of the sentence wrap on smaller screen sizes, I need to maintain the whole second sentence by breaking to the next line. Is this possible to do in just HTML & CSS?

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here, but seems like `<br />` tag would do the trick.

Comment: Yes, @Yogi, sorry that wasn't clear, but your example is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first sentence.br This is my second sentence that should be on the next line.

place **br** in tags <>

[implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUNi1.png)

[working result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14uvX.png)

for reference

[https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp#:~:text=The%20tag%20inserts%20a%20single%20line%20break](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp#:%7E:text=The%20tag%20inserts%20a%20single%20line%20break).

Comment: close, but I think OP wants a responsive rather than regular line break.